# Magic value collision between MachO fat binaries and Java class files

Tags: executable, binaryfiles, signature, executable-format

Both Java `.class` files and Mach-O fat binaries have the same magic signature, 0xCAFEBABE. When reading binary files, what's a good way to disambiguate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's Apple take on this:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-80.40.2/file/magic/Magdir/cafebabe.auto.html

> Since Java bytecode and Mach-O universal binaries have the same magic number, the test
> must be performed in the same "magic" sequence to get both right.  The long
> at offset 4 in a mach-O universal binary tells the number of architectures; the short at
> offset 4 in a Java bytecode file is the JVM minor version and the
> short at offset 6 is the JVM major version.  Since there are only
> only 18 labeled Mach-O architectures at current, and the first released
> Java class format was version 43.0, we can safely choose any number
> between 18 and 39 to test the number of architectures against
> (and use as a hack). Let's not use 18, because the Mach-O people
> might add another one or two as time goes by...

Here's a visual comparison:
[image]

So it seems currently Apple does the

```
(int32 at offset4) < 0x20
```

check to interpret it as `fat Mach-o` in their tools like command line `file` for determining file types.
Since even Apple calls it a hack unfortunately there's no 100% reliable method, but it seems that's your best shot. You can always be dealing with malformed (deliberately or not) `fat Mach-o files` or `Java class files` which may or may not be relevant for your use case.